# Поиск StringGrid

Tags: delphi

На форме имеется компонент `StringGrid` со значениями (данные вбиваются прямо в компоненте, никакой БД нету). Имеется поле `Edit` и кнопка. Необходимо осуществить поиск по первой колонке. Т.е. найти в первой колонке все значения соответствующие значению в `Edit`. Может кто подсказать, как это реализовать? В `PHP` я это сделал а вот Delphi давно не занимался, подзабыл как это делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у стринг грида есть свойства Cells ,Col, Row, aCol, aRow, ColMax и RowMax, ими и нужно оперировать в данном случае.

Делаете простой цикл for i:= 0 to RowMax - 1 do, и в теле цикла пробегаете каждую строчку и сравниваете ее со значением в Едит: if StringGrid1.Cells[MyCol, i] = Edit1.text then.

Answer (score 0):

Если искать нужно только в первой колонке, то используйте

```
i:=StringGrid1.Cols[0].IndexOf(Edit1.Text);
```

Это вернет либо номер строки, где совпало, либо -1